# not() for specific class

Tags: html, css

Suppose there is style for `div` and some more class's  -

```
div, .exceptDiv, .bigDiv {
    /*style...*/
}
```

[(here its jsFiddle),](http://jsfiddle.net/urielz/5ra5a/4/)

and I want to save a class which stay clear from any style  - `clearDiv` .

I tried  -

```
div:not(".clearDiv"), .exceptDiv, .bigDiv {
    /*style...*/
}
```

[(here its jsFiddle),](http://jsfiddle.net/urielz/v4YDD/3/)

but it doesn't work .

I'm looking for a solution which use `not(...)` if it possible  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `not()` correctly!

`div:not(".clearDiv")` is not valid, remove the quotes: `div:not(.clearDiv)`

http://jsfiddle.net/v4YDD/4/